# Python Optparse from Argument String

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

Typically one may simply call optparse's method `parse_args` without any arguments.  If, however, one needs to supply a different argument set than that of sys.argv, if may be passed to `parse_args`.

But what does one do if one needs to pass a string, not a list to `parse_args`?

I really need a function that does this:

```
>>> argument_string = "-a arga -b \"argument b\" arg1 arg2"
>>> parse_arguments(argument_string)"
['-a', 'arga', '-b', 'argument b', 'arg1', 'arg2']
```

Because

```
>>> argument_string.split(" ")
['-a', 'arga', '-b', '"argument', 'b"', 'arg1', 'arg2']
```

doesn't cut it.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what the [shlex](http://docs.python.org/library/shlex.html) module is for (well, it's one thing that it's for...):

```
>>> import shlex
>>> argument_string = "-a arga -b \"argument b\" arg1 arg2"
>>> l = shlex.split(argument_string)
>>> l
['-a', 'arga', '-b', 'argument b', 'arg1', 'arg2']
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the [shlex](http://docs.python.org/library/shlex.html) module for this:

```
>>> import shlex
>>> shlex.split("-a arga -b \"argument b\" arg1 arg2")
['-a', 'arga', '-b', 'argument b', 'arg1', 'arg2']
```